# How to change Wordpress Directories?

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory

How do I change the directories of Wordpress e.g.. /wp-admin or wp-login without messing up any internal files? I have tried this before but my Wordpress site stopped working.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: wordpress hard-codes directories/paths into the post data stored in the database. it's an incredible pain to migrate manually. there are migration tools documented on the WP site you can try. the one time I tried it, it seemed to work ok. But the overall experience (as with anything wordpress) just leaves you feeling dirty and abused.

Answer (score 0):

It is "possible", but *you will* **mess with internal files**.

This was already discussed in WordPress StackExchange. You'll find lots of links and references in this post:
[Can I rename the wp-admin folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106/12615).

This other one can be helpful for "white-labeling" WordPress:
[Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/12615)